# Why does +"" returns 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was just going through baNaNa and reached here
console.log(+"")

> 0
>   I am not able to find a possible explanation.

Comment: Unary plus does a `toNumber()` internally. check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

Answer (score 0):

Using `+""` is the same as using `Number("")`.
 It converts the string into a number.
 The string is empty so the value is `0`.

```js
console.log(+""); // 0
console.log(Number("")); // 0
console.log(+("0")); // 0
console.log(Number("0")); // 0
console.log(+"123"); // 123
console.log(Number("123")); // 123
console.log(-""); // same as `+""` but also negates the number
console.log(-"123"); // so this will be converted to a number, but also become a negative value
```

This way of parsing a number has a completely different behavior than `parseFloat` and `parseInt`. (Main difference is that `Number` tries to get the numeric value of any type of variable i.e. boolea, string, number, object... whereas `parseFloat` just reads the digits from a string).

```js
console.log(parseFloat("")); // NaN
console.log(+("")); // 0
console.log(parseFloat("1st")); // 1
console.log(+("1st")); // NaN
```